# Returning virtual columns in Phalcon models

Tags: php, model, phalcon

I have a model `leads_contents_interactions` for the (simplified) table:

```
CREATE TABLE `leads_contents_interactions` (
    `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `lead_content_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    `created_on` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=59 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I would like to select these and in addition to the `id`, `lead_content_id`, and `created_on` columns, I would also like it to return a column `is_new` where that is something like this:

```
SELECT 
    id,
    lead_content_id,
    created_on,
    IF(created_on > DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 DAY), 1, 0) AS is_new
FROM leads_contents_interactions;
```

Now I am aware I can do this with PHQL, but the `leads_contents_interactions` would ideally not be queried directly, I want this extra column to be returned when it is queried naturally like:

```
$leads = $user->getRelated(
    'leads',
    array(
        'Lead.deleted_by IS NULL',
        'limit'=>1000
    )
);

foreach($leads as $lead) {
    foreach($lead->interactions as $interaction) {
        echo $interaction->id."\t".$interaction->is_new.PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

**Model for Lead (simplified)**

```
class Lead extends PersendlyModelAbstract {

    public function initialize() {

        // A lead has multiple interactions, `contents`, through the weak entity `leads_contents`
        $this->hasManyToMany(
            'id',
            'LeadsContents',
            'lead_id',
            'id',
            'LeadsContentsInteractions',
            'lead_content_id',
            array('alias' => 'interactions')
        );
    }
}
```

**Model for LeadsContents (simplified)**

```
class LeadsContents extends PersendlyModelAbstract {

    public function initialize() {
        $this->belongsTo('lead_id', 'Lead', 'id', array('alias' => 'lead'));
        $this->belongsTo('content_id', 'Content', 'id', array('alias' => 'content'));
        $this->hasMany('id', 'LeadsContentsInteractions', 'lead_content_id');
    }
}
```

**Model for LeadsContentsInteractions (simplified)**

```
class LeadsContentsInteractions extends PersendlyModelAbstract {

    public function initialize() {
        $this->belongsTo('lead_content_id', 'LeadsContents', 'id', array('alias' => 'lead_content'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are wanting to add a column that doesn't exist on the table, but exists as a business rule (created_on > DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 DAY), 1, 0) then you need to add that rule in the afterFetch method of the model itself:

http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models.html#initializing-preparing-fetched-records

```
class LeadsContentsInteractions extends PersendlyModelAbstract 
{
    public $isNew;

    public function afterFetch()
    {
        $this->isNew = INSERT BUSINESS LOGIC HERE

    }
}
```

It should however be noted, that if you then use the method toArray() on the record set, that it will only use the columns that exist on the table itself.

http://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/498/afterfetch-

Comment: This is exactly what I was after. Thank you for the very thorough answer. Many thanks. b.

Comment: To circumvent such Phalcon 'limitation' of not including virtual fields in toArray(), I have provided a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45555178/466395

Comment: The link has expired. Is this method still valid?

Answer (score 2):

### Overriding toArray() Method for Virtual Fields.

In response to what David Duncan said:

> It should however be noted, that if you then use the method toArray()
>   on the record set, that it will only use the columns that exist on the
>   table itself.

And to circumvent such Phalcon 'limitation', I created the following method override.

#### Step 1

Basically, create a BaseModel.php and put the next code there.

```
/**
 * Method override.
 *
 * This method is inherited from Model::toArray()
 * https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/3.2/api/Phalcon_Mvc_Model
 *
 * We override it here to circumvent a Phalcon limitation:
 * https://stackoverflow.com/a/27626808/466395
 *
 * Basically, the limitation consists that, when one adds 'virtual fields' to a model (for example,
 * by way of callback methods like afterFetch()), then using toArray() on that model only returns
 * the fields in the database table but not the virtual fields.
 *
 * @access public
 * @param array $columns As per the Model::toArray() method.
 * @return array The data of the model, including any custom virtual fields.
 */
public function toArray($columns = null) {
    // calls the regular toArray() method
    $data = parent::toArray($columns);

    // then gets the model's virtual fields, if any
    $virtual_fields = [];
    if (!empty($this->list_virtual_fields)) {
        // iterates, to get the virtual field's name, value, and getter
        foreach ($this->list_virtual_fields as $name) {
            $getter_name = 'get' . \Phalcon\Text::camelize($name);
            $virtual_fields[$name] = $this->{$getter_name}();
        }
    }

    // merges the model's database data with its virtual fields
    $data = array_merge($data, $virtual_fields);

    return $data;
}
```

#### Step 2

Then, in any of your app models, define the list of virtual fields that will be included in the method override above. For example:

```
public $list_virtual_fields = [
    'status_label'
];
```

You should also define class properties, setters, and getters for those virtual fields. Just an example:

```
protected $status_label;
public function getStatusLabel() {
    return $this->status_label;
}
public function setStatusLabel(string $status_label) {
    $this->status_label = $status_label;
    return $this;
}
```

#### Step 3

Finally, set the value of virtual fields throughout your app. An example:

```
public function afterFetch() {
    $this->setStatusLabel('pending');
}
```

Note that my code uses getters and setters. You could change that if you wish.